# How can I save common OS X settings to be restored on a fresh install?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I often reset my Mac to a clean state by reinstalling OS X. Unfortunately I do not have enough space or budget for a complete Time Machine backup.

OS: Mavericks

Is there a way to grab my current settings and create a script that copies the following information:

1. Common settings in OS X such as wallpaper, Dock, Language & Region,
   Keyboard, Network settings (several static IP settings as backup and
   for a NAS).
2. Specific application settings such Android Studio and other App Store applications such as Divvy.
3. Environment variables

Out of Scope:

4. Backup/Restore customized contextual menu settings file under `Finder.app/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/Localizable.strings` (I learned how to change this setting on Super User, but if you have an idea on how to backup the setting, please let me know.)

Comment: Settings "such as wallpapers", or what else do you need to transfer? There are so many configurations one could set, and it's impossible to transfer *all* of this without Time Machine. By "rebuild" do you mean a complete reinstallation of OS X? Do you reinstall OS X so frequently that there's a real use case for this?

Comment: @slhck♦, I added the item "scripting target" and make my question more clearly than before. and it's same rebuild means as you and I have suspicious matter sometimes so I usually rebuild my mac once a month. If I could know about the way. It will help me to grow my skills about osx. Thank you for your advice. and I will be able to learn about common English in this site also.

Comment: Thanks for adding details – I reopened your question. Your English is good. I'm glad Super User helps you to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last time I did a clean reinstall I just copied the whole `~/Library/Preferences/` directory to the new installation, and I didn't run into any issues because of it. Settings for old versions of applications and machine-specific settings are usually ignored. `~/Library/Preferences/` is almost empty on a new installation, and if you delete all files there, the files are recreated when they are needed.

The settings for sandboxed applications are now stored in `~/Library/Containers/`. Network settings are stored in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` and settings for desktop pictures are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db`.

It might be easier to copy only `~/Library/Preferences/` and recreate other settings manually.

If you don't have backups, it is also possible to do a clean install on a new partition. Start up from the recovery partition, create a new partition from Disk Utility, choose Reinstall OS X, and select the new partition. You can then use Migration Assistant to transfer data from the old partition.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try it in a couple of days